# Haskell function implementation using lambdas

Tags: haskell

Is it necessary to convert all inputs to lambdas in Haskell?
I implemented map function only converting f to \f.
And it occurs error during runtime(attached below).

```
map_ xs = \f -> case xs of
                  [] -> []
                  y:ys -> (f y):(map f ys)
```

```
map_ square [3, 4]
ERROR - Type error in application
*** Expression     : map_ square [3,4]
*** Term           : [3,4]
*** Type           : [c]
*** Does not match : a -> b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it necessary to convert all inputs to lambdas in Haskell?

No. Indeed lambdas usually only appear in fancy higher-level abstractions.

From

```
case xs of
  [] -> ...
  y:ys -> ...
```

the compiler infers that `xs`'s type is a list. From

```
map_ xs = ...
```

the compiler infers that list is the first argument to `map_`.

But in your call to `map_`, you've put the function as the first argument; the list as second. The standard type for `map` in the `Prelude` is

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

IOW function first, list second.

So which do you intend?

Comment: I thought when i denotes 'map_ xs = \f -> ...', it meant i should input in the order of map_ f xs. Your solution really worked out. Thank you!

Comment: @blueMountain What ever gave you that idea? `map_` is simply a different name. Whereas with `map _` you would express that the first argument is completely ignored. Indeed there's also a syntactic shorthand for flipping around arguments, but it requires abuse of infix-section notation: ``(`map` xs) f``

Comment: `f x = ...` and `f = \x -> ...` are (mostly) equivalent. For "multiple" arguments, you peel them off in the same order; `f x y = ... ` and `f x = \y -> ...` and `f = \x -> \y -> ...` all (mostly) equivalent. (I say "mostly", because it's not worth getting into the subtle differences here... and because I can't give an accurate explanation of said differences.)